# Having Trouble Testing App On iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

Having a bit trouble testing my app on the iPhone. I just downloaded Xcode 8/Swift 3. I have already researched online various ways to test my app, since this is my first app to be tested on any device.

To my understanding, setting up a free account to test is doable. I have my account signed in and my device plugged in, so I went to Window -> Devices -> Install A New App. I go to click on my app, but the folder just opens and doesn't allow me to add my project (to even click on it). I also went under Product -> Destination and clicked on my device. Nothing appeared. I'm not sure what else to do in order to test my app on my device. Nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build and run your app with your phone plugged into your computer, and your phone selected as the build target in Xcode. Command-R is the keyboard command that should do that. You don't have to manually install the app, as build and run will do that for you.